# Jquery fade in fadeout div in onclick function not working

Tags: jquery, onclick, fadein, fadeout

Jquery fade in fadeout div in on click function not working

```
<div id="temporary_screenshot" style="display: none">
<div class="refresh_tabs" id="refresh_tabs1">
    <div>
        <div class="domin-gallery" id="domin-gallery1">

          <div>
            <img src="http://example.com/images/download.png" class="domin-gallery-bdr">
          </div>

          <div class="domin-link text-center" title="Last Update: 2018-05-24 06:07:59">example1.com</div>

          <div class="gradlink">

            <div class="domin-up-link">DOWN</div>

            <div class="redgrad">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="redgrad">&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="domin-up-link">DEFACED</div>

          </div>

          <div class="gradbdr"></div>
          <div class="gradredbox1"></div>
      </div>
          <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="box-gallery" id="website_status_gallery">
```

I have a number of websites. And I am updating its home screen shots in "temporary_screenshot". So each 10 minutes the screenshot is updating there. Then I am replacing the "screenshots" div from "refresh_tabs" to the to "website_status_gallery" one by one in 5 seconds interval with fade in effect .

```
            $($(hidden_id).html()).hide().prependTo("#website_status_gallery").fadeIn(1000);
```

What I want is on clicking on div 'gradbdr' I wrote a jquery to console print like this,

```
    $(".gradbdr").on("click", function() {

    console.log("******");

});
```

its not triggering.
when I try to edit it like

```
    $("#website_status_gallery").on("click", function() {

    console.log("******");

});
```

It giving the console output

Will fade in fade out event on click not work ???

Hope you to get clear idea.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I forgot to add that the data are fetching from AJAX and updating its corresponding div. response data is the whole div as string

Comment: You're missing a closing double quotation on $(".gradbdr").

Comment: no sir. this was error while copying I have edited the question.. I tried other div also. the issue no divs in inside the fading div triggering events

Comment: Can you give us a more coherent Javascript? So we can see the scopes and ajax and everything. It might just be that you add your eventlistener first, then replace the element by ajax, then the new element has no events.

Comment: If you are dynamically adding the div you need the event to listen outside of the generated element. eg. $(document).on('click','.gradbdr', function(){});

Comment: I tried the onclick function on the div itself that worked fine. I don't know why it not triggered on the Jquery event. thanks you guys for trying. I am going to continue because of some emergency work. I can't give the code because of this is very large javascript and I don't have time for that

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
$("body").on("click", ".gradbdr", function() {
    console.log("******");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

$("#website_status_gallery").click(function(){ console.log("******"); });

Comment: No explanation as to why this would work over his original function.

Comment: write in $(document).redy(function(){})

Comment: $(document).redy(function(){ $("#website_status_gallery").on("click", function() {

    console.log("******");

});});